# how to get ajax calendar extender position C#

Tags: c#, ajax, calendar

i like to set ajax calendar extender position in c# coding

so i tried below coding ....

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1"  runat="server" PopupButtonID="Image1"
                            CssClass="cal_Theme1" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="UCTxtdte1">
                        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

C#

```
 CalendarExtender1.PopupPosition = "Right";
```

but its showing error cannot convert string into  ajax calendar extender position

how to do it ....
where i made error ....
thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CalendarPosition is a type of enumeration (enum). To set it use:

```
CalendarExtender1.PopupPosition = AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarPosition.Right;
```